# Is there a way to force the browser to not cache?

Tags: yesod

That's pretty much it. The problem I am having depends on if a browser is caching or not. I need to force the browser to not cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following headers:

- Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
- Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT

The second can be any date in the past.

Edit: To do this in Yesod, have a look here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/0.9.3.3/doc/html/Yesod-Handler.html#g:8

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know what to do, I think I know where to look in the docs to follow through.

Answer (score 1):

```
alreadyExpired
```

[Yesod Haddock Docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/0.9.3.3/doc/html/Yesod-Handler.html#g:8)

Also, if you have control over the request (like an AJAX call) you can just add a random get param like ?sdasd=klfjlwkfj to be absolutely sure but I think that may be considered poor form.